# lock two columns inside flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make column A and column C fixed with a 100% height of the window, so they don't move when scrolling down? The container display has to be set to flex.

My middle column, C, is the only one I want to scroll/move down (when scrolling the whole window, the body).

I tried with position fixed and absolute but did not get it to work. i can not set a "left" value of the div's, as other surrounding elements (not in this example) are fluid so "left" is not an exact known value for me.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
}
.a,.c{
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:pink;
  display:inline-block;
}
.b{
  width:400px;
  background-color:tomato;
  display:inline-block;
  height:3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
      A
      <br/>lock
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    B
      <br/>scrollable
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    C
      <br/>lock
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%;` from `html`.

Then set the `.a, .c` to `height: 100vh;` and use `position: sticky;` with `top: 0;`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.a,
.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.b {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    A
    <br/>lock
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    B
    <br/>scrollable
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    C
    <br/>lock
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. i cant really remove height from body as its needed elsewhere. but your solution seem to work, even with keeping height on body. what was the reason for removing it if i may ask?

Comment: @nicole `height: 100%` on `body` is fine. It's the `html { height: 100%;}` which is causing the issue. "The `sticky` element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block " - so because there is no near ancestor to `html` it creates a stacking context in which `sticky` will not work. Read more on [`position sticky;` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky).

Comment: yes, my reset file has html,body{height:100%;} which I would like to keep so it doesnt break other things. but if there is no other way, i shall have to accept it.

Comment: @nicole why do you need `html {height: 100%; }`? You don't need it for the content to take 100% of the screen.

Comment: ok, cool. i shall remove it :)